# NullPointerException on onTextChanged

Tags: android, android-edittext, custom-component

I'm creating a rich text editor, so I have an extended EditText which receives a ViewGroup with child components. This ViewGroup is a toolbar with toggleButtons for bold and etc..

The EditText receives the toolbar this way:

```
private ViewGroup toolbar;

public CustomEditText(Context context, LinearLayout newToolbar) {
    super(context);
    toolbar = newToolbar;
}
```

With this code, the CustomEditText controls the visibility of the toolbar successfully:

```
@Override
protected void onFocusChanged(boolean focused, int direction,
        Rect previouslyFocusedRect) {       
    super.onFocusChanged(focused, direction, previouslyFocusedRect);

    if (focused)
        toolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    else
        toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

But unfortunately, by example, this returns a *NullPointerException*:

```
@Override
protected void onTextChanged(CharSequence text, int start,
        int lengthBefore, int lengthAfter) {
    super.onTextChanged(text, start, lengthBefore, lengthAfter);    

    toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

I know that it could be solved adding a TextWatcher to my CustomEditText in the current activity, but I'm trying to make the CustomEditText handle everything related to it.

Do you know why everything worked with **onFocusChanged**, but not with **onTextChanged**?

Comment: Check each variable to see if it's null. The CharSequence text might be null.